# Is it possible to obtain ARMA model from Lagrange formula for a linear dynamic system?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

For a SISO,  linear, continuos time system,  Lagrange formula applied to the output signal is:
$$ y(t)= \mathbf c^T(\Phi \mathbf x(0) +\mathbf\Psi u) +du=\mathbf c^T\Phi \mathbf x(0) +\mathbf c^T\mathbf\Psi u + du $$
And is also verified this property:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf\Psi u)=A\mathbf\Psi u +\mathbf bu$$
By deriving Lagrange formula and using the previous property we obtain:
$$ \dot y(t)= \mathbf c^T A \mathbf\Psi u + \mathbf c^T \mathbf bu  +d\dot u $$

$$ \ddot y(t)= \mathbf c^T A^2 \mathbf\Psi u + \mathbf c^T A \mathbf bu + \mathbf {c^T b }\dot u +d\ddot u $$
$$...$$
By doing a linear combination of the derivates of the output signal:
$$\alpha y(t)+\beta \dot y(t) +\ddot y(t)+... $$
Is it possible to obtain the ARMA model of the system?
Thanks.